# Can I use crashlytics in C++ desktop games?

Tags: c++, desktop-application, crashlytics, google-fabric

Is it possible to use crashlytics in C++ desktop games?

[Fabric's license agreement](https://fabric.io/terms?locale=en-us&utm_campaign=fabric-marketing&utm_medium=natural) states the following:

> *“Application” means any **mobile** application of Developer into which the Fabric Kit or any other Kit may be integrated.*

I was wondering if it would be okay to use Fabric Crash reporter (crashlytics) in non-mobile games even though the license agreement is specific to mobile applications?

Comment: The obvious answer seems to be "no".

Comment: As far as I can tell, it's only for iOS and Android. How were you planning on using it in a desktop app? Either way, licensing questions are between you and their lawyers and therefore off-topic for SO.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because software licensing terms are between you and their lawyers.

Comment: Fair enough. I agree it's pretty clear the intended use is just for mobile applications. I was wondering if there would be any support for non-mobile (desktop applications) but I guess that's more of a licensing question.

Answer (score 5):

Mike from Fabric here. We have no support for desktop games outside of our macOS support.

Comment: Thanks for the info!